# How to select ethernet ports for UDP connection?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, ethernet

I'm in a bit of a fix. I would say the main reason is because I haven't studied the OSI model completely.

I have a stream coming in as UDP input on the ETH0 port of my Linux machine. I perform some functions on it with my linux machine. Now I want to send another stream(from a named pipe) again as UDP output to the ETH1 port of the machine.

The input stream is coming from an encoder, and the output will also go to a Windows PC for testing.

Linux machine is Ubuntu OS 12.

Is this possible, and how can I achieve this? I would appreciate if you could tell me everything from scratch

Thanks

EDIT 1: Just to give you a taste of what is going on in my mind:

Let me try to break it down in lay man language (I believe that the answers are already enough lay-man for you guys, lol) but anyway :

I have a device that generates a video stream. That video stream is coming out of a cable that i plug into the hole in my CPU labelled "ETH0". Now there is something of an address which goes "UDP" and I can use this address to view the video stream on my linux machine. Now I do some fancy stuff on this (de-multiplexing, encoding, re-multiplexing) and Voila I have a "named pipe" that I want to then output to another device.

Now this other device is connected to my linux machine via a second cable plugged into the 'ETH1' hole in the CPU. I understand I will have to send data on that second cable in the form of "UDP packets" with a definite address (and port?).

How do I work out the details?
How do I 'choose' which UDP goes over which 'ETH' ?

Comment: You are using Ethernet and UDP. These don't have anything to do with the OSI model, which is both  defunct and inapplicble to anything extant in the real world. They *do* have something to do with the *TCP/IP* model, and the Ethernet model, although what an 'Ethernet port' is is beyond me. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I believe "ethernet port" here refers to a physical ethernet interface on a NIC.

Comment: Sorry for the poor choice of words, my brain has gone haywire with hours of googling and probably reading a lot of irrelevant stuff. By ethernet port, I wanted to say "The place where you insert the ethernet cable wire".

Comment: Kindly check EDIT1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to OS's IP router to decide what interface to use. Usually you don't really want to "push something out of eth1", because that would be, well, OSI level 1 operation. You work on level 3, so what you rather want is to "send something to such a place so sending thru eth1 is optimal".

The simplest solution would be to define a static route that tells the system that IP datagrams to a specific place should be sent through a specific interface, or through an interface with a specific IP. Both options are covered in [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168033/how-to-set-static-routes-in-ubuntu-server).

Comment: Hey! check out the edit please... It's too long for a comment

Comment: @vedantgala the answer's still the same. Set up static routes between PC and the second device and feel free to send datagrams to between them then. In the code, bind to the interface's IP address and send data to the device's address - Ubuntu will figure out what physical interface to use.

Comment: okay i have one last question; say I have datagrams that I want to output as UDP (and eventually send over ETH1). Say that address is udp://@229.1.1.11:5000. How do I know that this will end up over ETH1 and not ETH0? because at the same time from another address udp://@225.1.0.122:1234 is continuously receiving data (which came through ETH0).

Is there some additional address to assign before/after the udp://@229.... that will differentiate between the two ETH0 and ETH1? This is after I have defined static routes

Comment: @vedantgala no need to assign any additional things. In order to verify the routing, you could ping that remote device and have a program like wireshark to monitor the traffic. There you should see to which interface ping goes and from which interface pong comes.